# Building Hadoop on Windows Error: Ant BuildException

Tags: windows, maven, hadoop, ant

Trying to build Hadoop 2.4.1 on Windows Server 2012 using Maven 3.2.2 by running

```
mvn package -Pdist,native-win -DskipTests -Dtar
```

Currently getting the following error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-antrun-plugin:1.7:
run (pre-dist) on project hadoop-project-dist: An Ant BuildException has occured
: Execute failed: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "sh" (in directory "C:
\Hadoop\hadoop-2.4.1-src\hadoop-project-dist\target"): CreateProcess error=2, Th
e system cannot find the file specified
[ERROR] around Ant part ...<exec failonerror="true" dir="C:\Hadoop\hadoop-2.4.1-
src\hadoop-project-dist\target" executable="sh">... @ 31:104 in C:\Hadoop\hadoop
-2.4.1-src\hadoop-project-dist\target\antrun\build-main.xml
```

I've already dealt with the Java doclint issue described [here](http://blog.joda.org/2014/02/turning-off-doclint-in-jdk-8-javadoc.html). Is this a similar issue (i.e. I have to add something to the Ant configuration)?

Comment: Hi John , were you able to resolve this issue ? If So , please share the solution with us ...

Comment: Sorry, it's been a year and I don't have access to that computer anymore. My experience taught me that Windows and Hadoop do not play well together. I'm currently using Hadoop on a Mac.

Answer (score 2):

You must add [Cygwin](https://www.cygwin.com/) to the path.

Read this [article](http://www.blogjava.net/Bryan/archive/2014/08/22/417252.html) to know how to do that.

Comment: The official hadoop site mentions:
http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/Hadoop2OnWindows
Do not attempt to run the installation from within Cygwin. Cygwin is neither required nor supported.