# Hadoop on Windows Building Error

Tags: windows, hadoop, hadoop2, building

I had already install hadoop in my computer once, I deleted the source folder and I wanted to re-installed again. However I am failing at this error:

```
[INFO] Apache Hadoop KMS .................................. FAILURE [  8.050 s]
```

I tried everything I could find on internet but the error still persists.

**ERROR:**

```
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 09:50 min
[INFO] Finished at: 2016-07-27T14:57:47+02:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 97M/1061M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-antrun-plugin:1.7:
run (dist) on project hadoop-kms: An Ant BuildException has occured: exec return
ed: 2
[ERROR] around Ant part ...<exec dir="C:\Users\yzi1\hadoop-2.7.1-src\hadoop-comm
on-project\hadoop-kms\target" executable="sh" failonerror="true">... @ 10:121 in
 C:\Users\yzi1\hadoop-2.7.1-src\hadoop-common-project\hadoop-kms\target\antrun\b
uild-main.xml
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e swit
ch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please rea
d the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionE
xception
[ERROR]
[ERROR] After correcting the problems, you can resume the build with the command

[ERROR]   mvn <goals> -rf :hadoop-kms
```

**Help**

I have no idea what to do , I feel like I tried everything. Please help me solve this error.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried to run Hadoop on Windows Systems a while ago, my solution was always to use a Linux VM.  In your case I think ant can't find sh on your system.
If you really need to build Hadoop on Windows you may look here http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/Hadoop2OnWindows.
But again Hadoop on Windows is pain and only partial supported.

Comment: I already followed exactly the instructions in the link, but I still have this issue

Comment: did your found http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25271515/building-hadoop-on-windows-error-ant-buildexception? There is almost the same problem. If you look here: https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/exec.html, you see that sh is called, this command is not present on Windows. The Problem could also a "bug".

Comment: Found an other hint for building on Windows http://stackoverflow.com/a/32005348/2099531, unlike the wiki article it suggests to install cygwin.